# Grunt - Preserve directory structure when compiling files of a task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have the following task on my Gruntfile.js:

```
jade: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                pretty: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                flatten: false,
                cwd: 'app/views',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/',
                src: ['*.jade', 'views/{,*/}*.jade'],
                ext: '.html'
            }]
        }
    }
```

When I execute the task, the generated .html files are just dumped on the root of my dist folder completely disregarding the directory structure of the source. How can I preserve this directory structure?

Thanks,

Comment: You shouldn't need the `flatten` setting. What's the output if you run the task with the `--verbose` flag? Also would be helpful to see an outline of your project structure.